# Please could someone explain this rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please would someone explain in simple terms what these rules are doing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's matching any input (`.*`), and redirecting to the same location, setting the Environmental variables (`HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` and `HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH`) equal to the value in the http headers (`If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` respectively).

Basically it's just pulling some HTTP Header information and putting it in Environmental variables, presumably for future logic to take some action dependent on the variables.

Comment: The reason I ask is I'm investigating a possible intrusion and I didn't remember writing them. Could this be used maliciously?

Comment: @shanethehat These rules cannot make harm on their own.

Comment: Fair enough, then I shall look elsewhere. Thanks folks.